# Java Error in eclipse: Could not find or load main class length

Tags: java

I was working on eclipse normally. Suddenly, when I try to run I get this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class length
```

I made sure that the `PATH` environmental variable contains: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin`

What is the problem please ? I viewed previous posts but nothing help in my situation.

Comment: Check if "Build Automatically" is turned off. Use a package and never name classes using lower case!

Comment: Solved but don't know the reason. The class was in a project folder marked with red exclamation mark (though it is in the workspace). I moved the code to another project and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are either trying to run a class which no longer exists, or not longer has a main() method or the Run configuration is incorrect.

Do you really have a class called `length` (all lower case) ? That would be confusing.

Comment: Yes. It is just testing class to perform a small job.

Comment: Try doing cleaning and rebuilding your project.