# Java: Eclipse: Cannot Find Main Class

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-construction, compilation

I had a project that was compiling and running fine. I had also exported the build.xml file without issue. However, today, I clicked `Project` `-->` `Clean...`, and the project will no longer run. It raises the error:
`Error: Could not find or load main class com.bar.Foo`
Is there any way I can undo this?

Comment: Similar question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11861303/java-error-in-eclipse-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-length

Answer (score 1):

The answer is probably no, you cannot "undo" this. You can probably fix it by building your project, making sure that the project/class exists and that it contains a `public static void main(String ... args)` method.

Comment: I checked the `build.xml` file, though, and nothing changed. How could that be the case?

Comment: Check if the class is generated using the "Navigator" view. If it isn't then the build has not been performed. This can be due to "automatic builds" not being enabled, or because the stack of builders has become corrupted (in the project properties there is a "builders" part).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the file that you're trying to run was removed from the `src` folder.